# CakePHP mysql select day of month

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3

I hope to write correctly because I'm not very good in English.
I would select only the day of the month from MySQL but writes me an error.

**CONTROLLER**

```
$fields = array('id', 'nazov','DAY(datum) AS day','datum');
$data = $this->udalost->find('all',array('conditions'=>'MONTH(datum) = '.$month.' AND YEAR(datum) = '.$year,'fields'=>$fields,'order'=>'datum ASC'));
$this->set('data',$data);
```

**VIEW**

```
echo $data["day"];
```

**ERROR**

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: day [APP\views\udalosti\calendar.ctp, line 4]
```

**MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE `udalost` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nazov` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datum` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Can you tell me where I have error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug **$data** in your view:

```
debug($data);
```

If you call the find method, you'll usually get a multi dimensional array.

Also write the condition like this:

```
$data = $this->udalost->find('all',
    array(
        'conditions'=> array(
            'MONTH(datum) = '.$month,
            'YEAR(datum) = '.$year
        ),
        'fields'=>$fields,
        'order'=>'datum ASC'
     )
);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the index 'den', but you try to use it. (calendar.ctp, line 4).

Comment: Sorry it should be 'day' not den